# How to enable virtualization on a MacBook Pro (Windows 10) without bootcamp?

Tags: windows-10, mac, wsl2

So the situation is like this. I completely wiped off macOS from my late 2015 MacBook Pro and installed Windows 10 (for various reasons). I wanted to use WSL2 (and ubuntu) but I keep getting an error about virtualization not enabled. I tried to enable that and for some reason you can't do it without a systempreferences/boot thing on macOS but I don't have it.
Is there a way to enable virtualization on a MacBook running only Windows 10?

Comment: Since you cannot enable hardware virtualization from within Windows.  YOu are limited by what you can do due to your hardware.  If the only way to enable is to use the system preferences, then that is your only choice, so my suggestion is to perform that step THEN install Windows 10

Comment: Check [this answer to basically the same question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/234819) over on Ask Different.

Answer (score 0):

Intel VT-x is enabled by default. Exception, you don't have a compatible processor.
According to parallels.com you can check if the CPU is compatible with Intel VT-x:

- In the terminal type -> `sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu.features`.
- In the output text search for " VMX ".

You can take a "detour" and install VirtualBox or Parallels. Here you can see an option that may allow you to enable VT-x. But if this is grayed out, the CPU is not compatible or the option has been blocked by the MacBook itself.

OR

You could try to reset NVRAM. Hold the following command when starting the computer: <kbd>⌘</kbd> Command + <kbd>⌥</kbd> Option + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Problem: Apple doesn't give you a direct option, to enable VT-x, like we're used to with Windows etc.
I think this is "hidden" by Apple, for users, for good reasons.

Comment: It is virtually impossible to not have a compatible processor today and also in 2015. IIRC, there is a problem with Windows on MacBooks where hardware virtualization is only enabled after a specific reboot sequence involving macOS. [See here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/122071).

Comment: Even if it's virtually impossible, there could be a tiny chance that this asker runs exactly into a compatibility issue. Also, he uses no bootcamp